# Delete everything in a file name BEFORE the last occurrence of an Underscore in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have tens of thousands of files which will need to be renamed in large batches after being manually manipulated. All of the files will have a barcode followed by a unique identifying string of alphanumerics. They will all have the same .PDF extension as well. All files should have an underscore before the unique identifier.

For example: `12 44571 522110_10_E-354-98-U90368.ENG`
or : `14 44571 500169_9_Monroe NE_G-462-02-5674.GER`

What I need to keep after renaming these files is the unique identifier which looks like this:

```
 E-354-98-U90368.ENG
 G-462-02-5674.GER
```

I am not versed in Powershell and have found a 2-step process that works, but if there is an error in the file name, to begin with, it deletes the extension and the important unique identifier above.

The two-step process is this. 1st, get rid of the barcode and *#* after it for each file. If it does not have a name after this, then I'm done. If in the 2nd example, there is *Monroe NE* between the barcode and the unique identifier, I use the 2nd step.

How can I delete everything before the LAST occurrence of the Underscore in one step?

This is what I tried:

1st Step :

```
Get-ChildItem -File "Folder Path Name" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "Barcode", "" }
```

2nd Step:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Folder Path Name’ -File 
foreach ($File in $Files) {
  $Split = $File.Name -split '_'
  if ($Split.Count -gt 1) {
    Rename-Item -Path $File.FullName -NewName $Split[1]}}
```

Comment: Change `-NewName $Split[1]` to `-NewName $Split[-1]` (index `-1` will give you the last item in the array)

Comment: Here is the finished solution for those of us like myself who do not know how to code.

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Folder Path Name’ -File 
foreach ($File in $Files) {  $Split = $File.Name -split '_'
  if ($Split.Count -gt 1) { Rename-Item -Path $File.FullName -NewName $Split[-1]}}

Comment: If my answer below solves your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on its left. Otherwise please post an answer yourself (below) and accept that - in any case: don't use comments for code, doesn't format properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the *last* item in an array, use the index `-1`:

```
PS ~> $string = 'a_b_c'
PS ~> $split = $string -split '_'
PS ~> $split[-1]
c
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with 'Mathias R. Jessen's' helpful and succinct answer; here's another option to add to your arsenal of info.

```
'12 44571 522110_10_E-354-98-U90368.ENG', 
'14 44571 500169_9_Monroe NE_G-462-02-5674.GER' | 
ForEach-Object {$PSItem.Substring($PSItem.LastIndexOf('_')+1)}
# Results
<#
E-354-98-U90368.ENG
G-462-02-5674.GER
#>
```